# Xamarin.Forms SecureStorage Plugin doesn't work

Tags: xamarin.forms, token

I'm new with Xamarin.Forms, and I'm finding a way to store data in App like: token, username. Now, I'm trying to use `SecureStorgae`, but the function `getValue` doesn't work, and I have no idea why.

My code:

```
public async Task CheckLogin(string usernameString, string passwordString)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string url = "myUrl";
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { username = usernameString, password=passwordString });
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(json,Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url,content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var rs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResult>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                var token = rs.result.token;

                CrossSecureStorage.Current.SetValue("SessionToken",token);
                CrossSecureStorage.Current.SetValue("Username", rs.result.userName);
                var token1 = CrossSecureStorage.Current.GetValue("SessionToken");
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Home());
            }

        }
    }
```

When my app is running, I can't get the value of `SessionToken`.

Comment: no, i just use Application.Current.Properties instead :(

Comment: sorry for late reply

Answer (score 1):

> in iOS

Open the Entitlements.plist file and make sure that "Enable Keychain Access Groups" is checked. Also ensure that in Project->Options->iOS Bundle Signing, the Entitlements.plist is selected in Custom Entitlements for iPhoneSimulator platform.
[image]

> in Android

It is required that the password is set by the application prior to use.

```
SecureStorageImplementation.StoragePassword = "Your Password";
```

For more detail you can access [here](https://github.com/aftnet/SecureStoragePlugin)

Comment: Mark this as the answer